# Ruby on Rails - Stripe::CardError not catching blocked payments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am working on a subscription based website with content behind a paywall wired up with Stripe.  If the charge is declined or blocked, the account creation should cease and go back to the account create screen, with the error message.

Here's my exception code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  rescue_from Stripe::CardError, with: :stripe_card_error

  def stripe_card_error(e)
   flash[:error] = "#{e.error.message}"
   redirect_to request.referrer || "registrations#new" and return
  end

  def new
   #
  end
  def create
   #
  end
  //etc. etc.
```

It works fine for general card declines, however, when I run the test card numbers provided by Stripe that specifically say it will return fraudulent, the rescue does not trigger and the user account is created.

I got into my stripe dashboard and I can see the customer, subscription, etc. but the payment is blocked.

I would have thought the Stripe::CardError would catch this, but apparently not.

If a payment is blocked due to potential fraud, I don't want the user account to be created.
I want to treat it as a general card decline with appropriate error messages.

Is there another error I can rescue from or another way to do this?  I can't find anything in Stripe's API about the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe provides [a sample error handling snippet in their API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=ruby).  That snippet shows that you should be catching and handling all of the following:

- `Stripe::CardError`
- `Stripe::RateLimitError`
- `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` (this may be the one that applies to this specific situation)
- `Stripe::AuthenticationError`
- `Stripe::APIConnectionError`
- `Stripe::StripeError` (this may also be the one you want)

And, if all else fails, you should perform a general `rescue` to catch anything else.

You can perform only the general `rescue` and examine the error to determine which specific one is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I wired in all of the rescues you mentioned, but none of them catch a blocked payment.  It seems that Stripe just doesn't have a trigger for when a payment gets blocked.

Comment: Which test card number are you using?

Comment: 4100000000000019 and 4000000000004954 per Stripes testing page: 
 https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses

Comment: I just tested both of those and they throw `Stripe::CardError`.  What error type are you seeing?  What version of the stripe-ruby library are you using?

Comment: I am using gems 'stripe' v. 5.24.0 and 'stripe_event' v.2.3.1.  I forgot to mention in my original post that I am on Rails 6.0.3.2 with Ruby 2.7.1

Comment: Also, I do not see any errors.  Even the generic rescue does not trigger.

Comment: If a generic `rescue` isn't triggering and you're not seeing an error it sounds like this code isn't being called.  Can you add additional logging to see if you can pinpoint where code execution is stopping or forking off unexpectedly?